# Conditionally join from multiple tables based on a column?

Tags: r, join, dplyr

What I'm trying to accomplish is basically the equivalent of a vlookup in Excel with an if statement to determine which table to use based on the value of a given column.

Main dataset looks like this:

```
#STATE  CODE  AMOUNT
#  NJ    1     88
#  DE    2     75
#  VA    1     24
#  PA    1     32
```

Then there are a handful of other tables that I need to use for the lookups to add the factor column, depending on the state - some states are unique, and the rest all use a common table. For example (the actual tables are much longer than this):

NJ:

```
#CODE FACTOR
# 1    0.75
# 2    0.90
```

PA:

```
#CODE FACTOR
  1    0.80
  2    0.95
```

All Other:

```
#CODE FACTOR
  1    0.82
  2    0.93
```

So the final output would be:

```
#STATE  CODE  AMOUNT  FACTOR
#  NJ    1     88      0.75
#  DE    2     75      0.93   
#  VA    1     24      0.82
#  PA    1     32      0.80
```

Is there a way to conditionally join/lookup from the various factor tables depending on the value of State, in this example? Or would I need to combine the factor tables into a single table and explicitly list every state/factor combination and then join based on both State and Code? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The easiest way would be to combine the factor tables and then join by both state and code. I'm not sure what you mean by *"explicitly list every state/factor combination"*, but that doesn't sound like something you'd need to do as a separate step.

Comment: Are your factor tables actually named with the state abbreviations? `NJ` is the name of the data frame containing the New Jersey factor table?

Comment: @GregorThomas By explicitly listing the combinations, I mean right now there's 5 tables with 40 or so rows in them each - 4 unique states and 1 All Other. A combined table would need to combine the 4 unique state tables and add the state field , and then add the codes and factors from the all other table 46 times (that is, once for every other state). 

In the example above, the table would be 100 rows long - 2 lines for PA, 2 lines for NJ, and the same 2 lines from the all other table repeated 48 times for each of the other states.

The data frames are named like FACT, NJ_FACT, PA_FACT

Comment: Yeah, you don't need to do that---my answer and Ronak's answer show different ways of not doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having different dataframes for each state it would be easier if the data is present in one dataframe.

Here is one approach -

```
library(dplyr)

combined_states <- bind_rows(lst(NJ, PA, other), .id = "STATE") 

main %>%
  mutate(STATE_temp = replace(STATE, 
                      !STATE %in% unique(combined_states$STATE), 'other')) %>%
  left_join(combined_states, by = c('STATE_temp' = 'STATE', 'CODE')) %>%
  select(-STATE_temp)

#  STATE  CODE AMOUNT FACTOR
#  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 NJ        1     88   0.75
#2 DE        2     75   0.93
#3 VA        1     24   0.82
#4 PA        1     32   0.8
```

Note that the name of `other` dataframe should match with the `replace`d value for `STATE_temp`.

**data**

```
main <- tibble(STATE = c('NJ', 'DE', 'VA', 'PA'), 
               CODE = c(1, 2, 1, 1), 
               AMOUNT = c(88, 75, 24, 32))
NJ <- tibble(CODE = c(1, 2), FACTOR = c(0.75, 0.9))
PA <- tibble(CODE = c(1, 2), FACTOR = c(0.8, 0.95))
other <- tibble(CODE = c(1, 2), FACTOR = c(0.82, 0.93))
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of all data frames from your global environment with state abbreviation names, bind them into a single data frame with a STATE column, and join to the main dataset. Then for anything left over we can use `rows_patch` to fill in `NA` values.

```
library(dplyr)
state_tables = ls(pattern = paste(state.abb, collapse = "|")) |>
  mget() |>
  bind_rows(.id = "STATE")

main = main |>
  left_join(state_tables, by = c("STATE", "CODE")) |>
  rows_patch(other, by = "CODE")

main
#  A tibble: 4 × 4
#   STATE  CODE AMOUNT FACTOR
#   <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 NJ        1     88   0.75
# 2 DE        2     75   0.93
# 3 VA        1     24   0.82
# 4 PA        1     32   0.8
```

(Using Ronak's kindly shared data)

Comment: Trying to run this I get:
Error in `rows_patch()`:
! `x` key values must be unique.

Comment: Looks like [this has been fixed in the most recent version of `dplyr`, 1.0.9](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/news/news.html).  From the release NEWS, *"The `rows_*()` functions no longer require that the key values in `x` uniquely identify each row."*

Comment: That's what I get for not checking if I was up to date. Works great now, thanks!

Comment: I'm usually a few versions behind on dplyr (and most things), but recently got a new computer so everything's fresh! I'm glad to see the `rows_*` functions being actively developed, I find them very useful :)